# HTML text into microsoft word document bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a small web rich text editor that have some features like bolb, italic, and so on...

The text generated is html, and I would like to insert that text inside a word document bookmarks.

Putting the text into the bookmarks is not a problem. However, I have problems because of the text format (with the bolds for example).

Is there a fast way to "convert" text from html to doc, or just a way to include html into a word document?

This is an exemple:

```
 <p>Hello <strong>world<strong/></p>
```

This text should just appear "Hello **World**" in the word bookmark.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing the html in  ... <\body> tags should do the trick.

Comment: This didn't work for me. All I got was `<body>...</body>` appearing in my document.